# Excel Macro to Insert Row, with formatting, below header of named range

Tags: excel, vba

I would like the user to be able to click the green button on the right of each named range to insert a new data entry row below the named range header.  The code I have hard codes the insert row number for the first named range.  I need a way to have the code to be smart enough to know that the first row below the header of the second, third, & forth named range will changed.

Another big part is that the inserted row needs to have the same formatting (dropdowns, formulas, color, etc.) as the rows below.

[image: Image of Data Entry Worksheet]

```
First named range button code:

Sub BidSheetAddRow_Materials()
'   BidSheetAddRow_Materials Macro

    Rows("19:19").Select

    Selection.Copy

    Rows("19:19").Select

    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

    Range("A19").Select

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Selection.ClearContents

    Range("C19").Select

    Selection.ClearContents

    Range("K19").Select

    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the buttons, using a `beforedoubleclick` event, and tie the event to cells, e.g., `if not intersect(target, columns("AP")) then // Select Case`, so you can utilize `target.row`, etc.?

Comment: I have am looking this up as an option.  I have never heard or thought about using something like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the screenshot all table headers are in colA, the first input row is 3 cells below the header, and the first input cell on each table row is a merged cell.

So this works for me:

```vb
Sub AddMaterial()
    AddRow "MATERIALS"
End Sub

Sub AddRate()
    AddRow "RATE"
End Sub

Sub AddRow(TableHeader As String)
    Dim f As Range, ws As Worksheet, c As Range
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input")                        'or whatever
    Set f = ws.Columns("A").Find(what:=TableHeader, lookat:=xlWhole) 'find the header
    
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        Set c = f.Offset(3)                             'step down to first input row below header
        Do While c.Offset(1).MergeArea.Cells.Count > 1  'keep looping while `c` is merged
            Set c = c.Offset(1)
        Loop
        c.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown 'insert
        c.EntireRow.Copy c.Offset(1)               'copy
        c.Offset(1).EntireRow.ClearContents        'clear new row
    Else
        MsgBox "Table header '" & TableHeader & "' not found!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Before/after:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I am not great with VBA and for some reason I keep getting an error when I try to run the code in my workbook.  It says "subscript out of range" or it wants me to select a macro.  Any ideas where I messed up at?

Comment: Put the code in a regular module, change the sheet name from "Input" to whatever your actual sheet name is.  Link each button (I use shapes for buttons since the formatting has more options) to the appropriate Sub (2 examples above for adding a row to MATERIALS and RATE).  Add any additional subs for the other tables.

Comment: Thanks for that guidance.  Now I am getting the error "Table Header Not Found". :(

Comment: If that's happening then whatever header you're passing (eg "MATERIALS") is not matching any value in Col A of the sheet.  I can't say what the specific fix is there...

Comment: The "header" is a named range, not a "table".  Is there another way to designate that row as a "header" row?

Comment: It just looks for a cell with the exact text "MATERIALS" in Col A - it's not using any named range.

Comment: I unmerged the gray header line and made it a named range and now i no longer get the error for trying to find the header.  It looks like it is inserting the row at the bottom of the list without bringing in the formulas.  I can work with the insert at the bottom as longs as it keep the formulas.

Comment: Better phrasing of the question - how do I modify the code so that it only blanks out the data in row A, O, and AH and not the entire row?

Comment: `c.Offset(1).EntireRow.Range("A1,O1,AH1").ClearContents`  That range address looks odd but `Range()` is *relative to the range it's called on* (typically it's the whole sheet so you don't notice that...)

Comment: Says "can't do that to a merged cell". :(

Comment: got it!  c.Offset(1).EntireRow.Range("A1:M1,O1:Q1,AG1:AJ1").ClearContents  Thank you soooo much for your help!  You are a rockstar!!